# Haskell type definition is wrong

Tags: haskell

I am just starting to learn Haskell and I have the assignment to use higher order functions to create a function with the following type definition

```
-- compr :: (a->b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The function is not relevant, can be the simplest functions so my idea was like this:

```
identity x = x
booleans x | x == 1  = True
           | x ==0 = False
           | otherwise = False

compr identity booleans xs  =  filter booleans(map (identity) xs)
```

but this function has this type

```
compr :: (a->b) -> (b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
```

I have tried everything but with no positive results. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Hint: you need to write a function that takes a "transformation" function `(a -> b)`, a "predicate" `(a -> Bool)`, a list of `a`s, applies the "transformation" only to the members of `[a]` for which the predicate holds true, and returns a list of resulting `b`s. You have to apply `filter` first, and `map` after it.

Comment: I would expect your function to actually have the type of `comp :: (a -> a) -> (int -> bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. The identity function must return the same type as it was given. You need a function that modifies it's argument.

Comment: thanks very much i was on the right track , i applied map first then filter

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it, but you need to apply the filter before the map. In that way, the filter applies to `[a]` instead of `[b]`, and the predicate gets the right type.

```
> compr identity booleans xs  = map identity (filter booleans xs)
> :t compr
compr :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
```

By the way, I find the names you use for your variables to be misleading. For instance, the `identity` variable in the definition of `compr` has nothing to do with the `identity` function you declared before.

I'd suggest you use more generic variable names instead, e.g.

```
> compr f p xs  = map f (filter p xs)
```

where `f` stands for "function" and `p` for predicate.

Comment: @leo23082014, be kind to yourself <3

Answer (score 0):

There is already a standard library function in Haskell called `id` (`id :: a -> a`) to replace your `identity` function. So accordingly depending on how you will define your `booleans` function you might simplify your `comp` function as follows;

```
booleans x | x == 1    = True
           | otherwise = False

compr :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
compr =  filter booleans . map id

*Main> compr booleans [1,2,3,4]
[1]
```

Comment: `booleans = (== 1)` would be even simpler.

Comment: @4castle totally